# Filename too long in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am currently writing a small program in Octave (3.8.0, on Windows) to parse a directory structure and retrieve some data from files in that structure. The files of interest are not always in the same consistent location, so I have to search for them, and to do so, I make extensive use of the `dir` function.

I have come up against an issue, which I don't know how to solve. For some files, I get the following warning when calling the dir function:

```
warning: dir: 'lstat (P:\9xxxProjects\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla\long_filename)' failed: No such file or directory
```

and the resulting elements in the structure output from `dir` are:

```
>> test.name
ans = .
ans = ..
ans = [](0x0)
ans = [](0x0)
ans = [](0x0)
ans = [](0x0)
ans = [](0x0)
```

which makes my code error out.

Now, I have created a test directory in the base `C:\` drive (`C:\Test`), copied the files across, and without changing anything else (i.e. leaving the file names unchanged), ran the same code. It ran just fine, no issues with `dir`.

Is there a maximum path/file length that is supported by `dir`? How can I work around this problem? I cannot change the naming convention of either the directory structure or the file names. The length of the path to the problem directory is 177, the length of the file names that give me problems is 84, so a combined length of 261. Other files in that same directory, of length 81 (so combined length of 258), work just fine. Is there a maximum length of 260 characters somewhere in the code?

I have narrowed down the issue to the the call to `lstat` and `stat` in `dir`:

```
[st, err, msg] = lstat (fn);
if (err < 0)
   warning ("dir: 'lstat (%s)' failed: %s", fn, msg);          
else
   ## If we are looking at a link that points to something,
   ## return info about the target of the link, otherwise, return
   ## info about the link itself.
   if (S_ISLNK (st.mode))
     [xst, err, msg] = stat (fn);
     if (! err)
       st = xst;
     endif
   endif
```

Here's what I get when I call `lstat` and `stat` with my problem file/directory:

```
>> [st, err, msg] = lstat(fullfile(problem_dir,file_name_test))
st = [](0x0)
err = -1
msg = No such file or directory

>> [xst, err, msg] = stat(fullfile(problem_dir,file_name_test))
xst = [](0x0)
err = -1
msg = Filename too long
```

Unfortunately, both `stat` and `lstat` are built-in/compiled functions so I can't edit them. Can anybody suggest a workaround?

Comment: you say "...both stat and lstat are built-in/compiled functions so I can't edit them.". However, if you type `which lstat` it tells you what file to edit.  Here's the source for [stat](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/c304687571c8/libinterp/corefcn/syscalls.cc#l922) and [lstat](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/c304687571c8/libinterp/corefcn/syscalls.cc#l782). You'd need to rebuild Octave after this though.  Anyway, as already mentioned, such long filepaths don't work properly in Windows systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum path length [to be used on Windows is 260](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx). You may work around this issue but you will probably run into the next. I strongly recommend to change the struchture as other octave functions and other software will run into similar issues.

If you really can`t change the structure, try to create symbolic links to have an alternative shorter structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will see if I can change at least the file names to something shorter. I haven't heard about symbolic links before, can you explain how to do this or at least point me towards the relevant resource(s)?

Comment: Basically, you create a symlink `P:\short\` for `P:\9xxxProjects\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla` so you can use `P:\short` instead of the long name. As both point to the same filesystem object, the content is identical. If you are using NTFS check "NTFS symbolic link" and "NTFS junction point" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point

Comment: @am304 I don't have a windows system to test it but the documentation linked suggests that pre-pending `\\?\` to the path should work. Have you tried `\\?\C:\your_very_long_filepath`?

Comment: It looks like the easiest thing to do will be to rename the offending files so that the combined path length is under 260 characters. The whole P: drive is read-only at the moment, while IT are transferring the files over to a new drive, with larger capacity (it's a network drive). They are having issues with long filenames :-) so it's taking longer than expected. Once it's back to being writeable, I'll try again and report back.

Comment: It turns out that there were far too many files to rename for this to be scaleable, so I ended up solving the problem with `subst X: "P:\9xxxProjects\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla"` in a DOS command window, and then working on `X:`. Seems to work OK so far.